# When using patchValue method to update form value, form becomes dirty?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have to know concept of patchValue method. when using **patch value method to update form value, form becomes dirty**.

```js
// using this way

setTimeout(() => {
      this.skillForm.patchValue({
        date: [new Date()],
      });
    }, 1000);
```

sample :  [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xl8yfq-jp4u6y?file=reactiveform.component.ts)

**But, if i use like below form wont become dirty**

```js
setTimeout(() => {
       // workaround for this scenario
      this.skillForm.controls['date'].patchValue(new Date());

    }, 1000);
```

sample link :  [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xl8yfq-6zumty?file=reactiveform.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

> updated sample [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xl8yfq-lvkbt9?file=reactiveform.component.ts)

**you have to use this way, it wont add ng-dirty class**

```js
 setTimeout(() => {
       this.skillForm.patchValue({
       //compare this
              date: new Date(),
          });
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: In angular, ng-sirty class gets added only when form UI gets updated........when we changes value ofform programaticlly, ng-dirty class wont add

Comment: @kumaresan_sd I see, but please confirm your source. Example 1, the patchValue is date: [new Date()] , it is **Array**, but second not, it is reason of why different.

Comment: i think you did not get my issue

Comment: In fact, I spent more then half hour there, and read the source between formGroup.patchValue and control.patchValue, and finally is because your source reason. please copy it to your source and run: `setTimeout(() => {this.skillForm.controls['date'].patchValue([new Date()]);}, 1000);` the dirty message there, right?

Comment: and you also can copy it and run `setTimeout(() => {this.skillForm.patchValue({date: new Date(),});}, 1000);` the dirty message lost.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i have already tried and that works fine for me.....can you please tell why we have do this way....instead of  setTimeout(() => {this.skillForm.patchValue({date: [new Date()],});}, 1000);

Comment: okay, i will accept this as a answer...please vote this question...it will bw helpfull for someone......

Comment: Thanks for your help :)